# Setting an int so it is always the greater value?

Tags: java, int, comparison

I have a simple function as defined below:

```
if(currentValue < smallestValue)
 {
    smallestValue = currentValue;
 }
```

- CurrentValue can be any value of int.
- All my values are ints

What can I initialize smallestValue to so it will always be greater than the first currentValue?

Comment: Why do you even need an if-Statement when the outcome will always be true? Why do you even need to compare these values when the outcome is predetermined?

Comment: @Gumbo Because the if statement is within a loop. I left the loop out as I figured it weren't relevant to the question.

Comment: But what does the loop change if one value is **always** bigger the outcome will **always** be the same, loop or not.

Comment: With the loop included I don't want it to always be bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this rule: *CurrentValue can be any real number*, use [`Double.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE):

```
double smallestValue = Double.MAX_VALUE;
```

But the second rule negates the previous: *All my values are ints*, so use [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

```
int smallestValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: You're right. I guess I should say CurrentValue can be any int. I'll edit this now.